# Change tabindex dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Imagine this simple layout ( http://jsfiddle.net/4F9cL/ ). 
We have a table, for each row i have a label a textbox and a checkbox.
The first textbox has tabindex = 1 , the first checkbox has tabindex = 2, the next textbox on the second row has tabindex = 3 and so on.

What i would like to do is change the tabindex on the checkbox on the same row for the textbox that im in if the content of the textbox has changed.

For example at the moment im checking the checkbox on the row that the thebox content has been changed, i do that with the following code:

```
 $("input:text").change(function () {
            $(this).parents('tr:first').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

So the scenario is the following: If the content of the textbox hasnt changed, when i tab i want the focus to change to the checkbox on the same row. If the content of the textbox HAS changed, i would like the focus to be on the next textbox on the row below INSTEAD of the checkbox on the same row.

I hope i explained it good enough for you to understand what im trying to do.
I've tried using .removeprop() and .removeattr() but that doesnt work and when next tab hits it just goes to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input:text").change(...);
```

The `change` event of a textbox **will only be executed once the textbox loses focus**. This means that when you press Tab, that function has not yet run, and you'll end up with your old tabindex target.

```
$("input:text").keyup(...);
$("input:text").keydown(...);
```

These events will fire when you either press down on (keydown), or release (keyup) a button while the textbox is focused.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$("input:text").keyup(function() {
    var textBox = $(this);
    var textBoxIsEmpty = textBox.val().length == 0; //I assume you use this to determine which element should be the next to get focused when pressing tab.

    var currentTabIndex = parseInt( textBox.attr("tabindex") );

    var nextTarget = GetNextTarget(textBoxIsEmpty); //not sure how you define this. This is the item you want to be your next target when you press tab.
    var nextTabIndex = currentTabIndex + 1;

    nextTarget.attr("tabindex", nextTabIndex);
});
```

Although I am not 100% sure if changing the tabindex dynamically works in every browser.

Comment: So i tested with:
$("input:text").keydown(function () {
                $(this).parents('tr:first').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('tabindex');
            });

This removed the tabindex all together on the checkboxes. Now i need this to trigger only when the content of the textbox im at has changed. Do you know how?

Comment: Did you check the variables I added in my snippet? I put a boolean in there under the name `textBoxIsEmpty`. Basically, allmy snippet is missing is the code piece on how you select what the next item should be, based on that boolean (that's what the magic function `GetNextTarget(bool)` is supposed to do in my example)

Comment: The textboxes will always be populated with information, they will never be empty. Sorry for not clarifying this earlier.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to keep track of the **initial value** of the textbox (e.g. store all intitial values in a list when the page has just loaded), and then compare that to the **current value** of the textbox (make sure you retrieve the correct **initial value** from the list you compiled earlier). Then you end up with a similar boolean, and the rest of the code is still correct.

Comment: shouldn't this suffice:        $("input:text").focusin(function () {
            textBoxContent = $(this).val();
        }); 
then i can just check on keydown if $(this) differs from textBoxContent and if it does i remove the tabindex

Comment: Yes, partly. But what happens if you've already changed a textbox, and at a later time go back to it? It will once again try to track differences between what is now the initial value, and what you will change it to this time. If that check can be done every time, then your suggestion is good. But if you are only allowed to check against the **initial value at page load**, rather than the **initial value at focusing the textbox**; your suggestion does not hold true. Not sure which you want, this requires more knowledge of the environment and intentions of the form and/or application.

Comment: The check has only to be done with the value that was in the textbox before it was edited, this is regardless if the value has been changed before or not.

Comment: Then you need to make sure you still know what that value was before someone edited it. I suggest taking note of all values when the page has finished loading, so you know for sure that the user hasn't already fiddled with it. We're going quite out of scope from your original question on how to change the tabindex attribute, however :) If there are other issues, I suggest you post a different question.

Comment: Yeah, got alot more off track then i was supposed to :)
the system im building, i know that the user is gonna use tab key so i ended up with this:

        $("input:text").focusin(function () {
            textBoxContent = $(this).val();
        });

        $("input:text").keydown(function (ev) {
            if (textBoxContent != $(this).val() && ev.keyCode == 9) {
                $(this).parents('tr:first').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('tabindex');
            }
        });

Comment: so basically i save the content of the textbox when the user enters it. When he presses tab key, if the content has changed from the saved value the tabindex is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like that and it's working fine for me.
before applying this you should clear on this you have declare you tabindex in the input properly.

```
jQuery("input:text").keyup(function() {    
  currentTabIndex = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr("tabindex") );
  nextTabIndex = currentTabIndex + 1;
  jQuery('input[tabindex='+nextTabIndex+']').select();
});
```